# Nested block and getChildHtml() in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have some trouble when i get data with function getChildHtml() . 
Here is my layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <hello_index_index>
          <reference name="content">
               <block type="hello/hello" name="title" template="hello/title.phtml">
                      <block type="hello/hello" name="title1" template="hello/title1.phtml">
                            <block type="hello/hello" name="title2" template="hello/title2.phtml"/>
                      </block>
               </block>
          </reference>
    </hello_index_index>
</layout>
```

when i try print data in file title2.phtml to the screen with code is

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('title2');
```

**OR**

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('title1');
```

In the first way is no data displayed on the screen . 
In the second way have data displayed on the screen but only data in file title1.phtml . 
So how to display the data in file title2.phtml 
Thank everybody .

Answer (score 0):

As your code example is somewhat obscured, it's difficult for me to understand what your blocks actually are and/or do.
Remove the association between "title1" and "title2", then try rendering your block(s) with `getChildHtml` again.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <hello_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block name="title" template="hello/title.phtml" type="hello/hello">
        <block name="title1" template="hello/title1.phtml" type="hello/hello" />
        <block name="title2" template="hello/title2.phtml" type="hello/hello" />
      </block>
    </reference>
  </hello_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <block type="hello/hello" name="title" template="hello/title.phtml">
                  <block type="hello/hello" name="title1" template="hello/title1.phtml">
                        <block type="hello/hello" name="title2" template="hello/title2.phtml"/>
                  </block>
           </block>
```

in title.phtml write $this->getChildHtml('title1'); and in title1.phtml write 
$this->getChildHtml('title2')

because magento blocks can render only "child" blocks when using "getChildHtml()"